# Hiding the current page of a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a little question, related to a UIPageViewController. I use Swift as language, but if someone is unfamiliar with this new language, I understand Obj-C code too. My problem is relatively simple to describe, but not so simple to solve. I have a UIPageViewController set up. At some point, if the user pushes the current page of the page controller to the bottom, the page should disappear (the current view controller removed). I've tried a couple of things already. Before I continue, I'll explain some of the mechanics of my UIPageViewController that may help for an easier answer:

the page controller does not swipe trough an array of pre-configured view controllers. At the beginning, it takes in just one view controller. The rest of view controllers are calculated while the user swipes, trough the data source methods:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
...
}
```

and

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
...
}
```

Each of the view controllers added, is an instance of a custom view controller that takes in a index, which indicates the data that this view controller should load. The limit of the pages in the page controller is defined by a count of the items available for the custom view controllers to load.

I've tried just one thing, and it almost worked. I'm describing it now that you know my page controller mechanics:

1. I swipe the current page down and it (graphically) disappears
2. I'm removing the data element linked to the current (and recently "deleted") view controller from the folder where all the others are stored
3. I'm updating the count of the elements inside the folder

The only problem with this solution is that after all this I still need the user to swipe to see the updates... Let me explain: after the current view controller disappears , I still have a white canvas in front of me... Only after the user swipes to get to a new page, the two data source methods are executed and the updates go live. After the swipe, the blank canvas is not there anymore (if I swipe back) and all other controllers are shown correctly. I just need to do one simple thing: after the view controller disappears, I should automatically (programatically) swipe back to the view controller before, so that the two data source methods are called and everything is updated...

So at the end, maybe my question should me more like: "How do I programatically swipe back to the previous UIPageViewController page?"

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` method of your UIPageViewController.  You can do this right after step 3 above.  It's your choice as to whether to use the viewController for the data element before the one removed, or the one after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPageViewController/setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:).